# Autocomplete with multiple values using remote data

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

**My aim:** To be able to get autocomplete with multiple values from a remote source

**My stack:** AngularJS for front-end, [Awesomplete](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete) and Node for backend

I can find the examples in the Awesomplete documentation for:

1. Multiple value autocomplete based on a local data-list
2. Getting the data from remote URL and using it's response for auto-completetion

**My problem:** I can't seem to combine them to do both.

From the awesomplete documentation:

**Multiple value auto-completetion:**

```
<input data-list="CSS, JavaScript, HTML, SVG, ARIA, MathML" data-multiple />

new Awesomplete('input[data-multiple]', {
filter: function(text, input) {
    return Awesomplete.FILTER_CONTAINS(text, input.match(/[^,]*$/)[0]);
},

replace: function(text) {
    var before = this.input.value.match(/^.+,\s*|/)[0];
    this.input.value = before + text + ", ";
}
})
```

**And Ajax example:**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/lang/fr", true);
ajax.onload = function() {
    var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).map(function(i) { return i.name; });
new Awesomplete(document.querySelector("#ajax-example input"),{ list: list });
};
ajax.send();
```

What I am after is to be able to have multiple keywords autocompletion but based on a remote response, which I am struggling to do. I am mostly a back-end developer and so my understanding of the front-end is not very vast, as you can already guess.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with [angucomplete](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete) but that still didn't have a solution for the multiple value search.

However, I realised that the Awesomplete Ajax example gets the data from a URL pulled down and then you filter it via the front-end with the search. That is not a proper solution as you will have so much unnecessary data on your browser. Angucomplete, on the other hand, appended the text value to the URL so you could use it as a query parameter.

So what I did was open up the angucomplete Angular module and modified it. Doesn't look like there is a solution so I had to create is from scratch to support the multi value support.